# Python: Is there a way to print only a specified character from a string, and let the others blank?

Tags: python, printing

I am new to Python programming and I wanted to make a little hangman code.
I am nearly done with it but there are a few things which for the moment are incomplete. I have tried to find an appropriate answer to my
issues but I've found nothing so I hope you will help me.

Let`s just say that there are the following lines of code:

```
word = "testing"
guess = input("Tell me a letter ")

if guess in word:
    print("You are correct. This letter is at the index " + str(word.index(guess)))
```

I have 2 questions:

1. What do I have to do in order to print the guessed char and let the others blank?
   e.g.  Let's assume that I guessed the letter `i`, so this letter is at the index no 4, so I want to print it so it will look like this:
   `xxxxixx`
2. The string testing contains 2 `t` characters. If I guess the `t` char then I can only see the first `t` and not the second:

   ```
    Tell me a letter t
    You are correct. This letter is at the index 0
   ```

What can I do to reveal also the second char at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

One of the better solutions, I think, is to define a function that, given the `word` and the guessed letters (knowing which is the currently guessed letter), will return you the `tXXtXXX` result, as well as the positions of the guessed letter.

Here's what it can look like:

```
def get_positions_and_partial_word(word, current_guess, all_correct_guesses=[]):
    """Given a word (like "testing"), the current guess (like "t"),
       and a list of correct_guesses so far, this function will return
       a list of the positions of the guess (which will be empty if not
       a correct guess), and the partial word (like "tXXtXXX")."""

    current_guess_positions = []
    partial_word = ""

    # Populate the current_guess_positions and the partial_word:
    for i,c in enumerate(word):
        if c == current_guess or c in all_correct_guesses:
            partial_word += c
        else:
            partial_word += "X"

        if c == current_guess:
            current_guess_positions.append(i)

    return current_guess_positions, partial_word
```

Do you see what's going on?  I want to return the positions of the current guess (there can be more than one, so I return a list), and I want to return the partial word.  So I loop through the characters (`c`) in the `word`, keeping track of the index (as `i`), and create (letter-by-letter) the `partial_word`, and add the position to the `current_guess_positions`.  When the loop is done, I return them.

You can call it like this:

```
positions, partial_word = get_positions_and_partial_word('testing', 't', [])
```

Then `positions` will be set to `[0, 3]`, and `partial_word` will be set to `tXXtXXX`.

If it's correct, you will still need to add the letter to a list of correct guesses (which is needed to pass in as the last argument to the `get_positions_and_partial_word()` function), but I'll let you figure that out on your own.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

I turned your code into a function for easier use and also printed the guessed word after every round.

Also I changed the default character from `x` to `*` because `x` could be in some words.

```py
def hang(word, tries):
    guesses = list('*'*len(word))
    for enum in range(tries):
        guess = input('Letter please (' + str(tries-(enum+1)) +' guesses left) ')
        for (index, char) in enumerate(word):
            if guess == char:
                guesses[index] = char
        newword = ''.join(guesses)
        print(newword)
        if newword == word:
            print('you win')
            return None
    print('you lost')
```

```
>>> hang('testing', 6)
Letter please (5 guesses left) e
xexxxxx
Letter please (4 guesses left) t
textxxx
Letter please (3 guesses left) s
testxxx
Letter please (2 guesses left) i
testixx
Letter please (1 guesses left) n
testinx
Letter please (0 guesses left) g
testing
you win
```

Hope this is what you wanted!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am also a leaner of python programming, I tried my best to answer your question

```
str=''
guess='t'
word='testing'
for char in word:
    if(char==guess):
        str+=guess
    else:
        str+='x'
```

and that will give you the answer

```
'txxtxxx'
```

hope you got a solution..:)

Answer (score 0):

1. In order to print the guessed char and let the other chars blank, you can create another string of same length as original string and then replace its characters as you guess them.
2. If you guess a letter and it appears multiple times in the string, then you should search for all the occurences of that character, and replace all of them.

I've written this very basic code to answer your two questions:

```
a = "testing"
b = "-------"


while a != b:
    c = input()
    i = a.index(c)
    idxs = [i]

    while i != -1:      ### Searching for all occurences of character c
        ix = i+1
        i = a.find(c, ix)
        idxs.append(i)

    bl = list(b)
    for i in idxs[:-1]:     ### Replacing all indices
        bl[i] = c

    b = ''.join(bl)
    print(b)
```

Please comment if you have any doubt. Thanks